# Regex for French telephone numbers

Tags: regex

I'm trying to implement a Regex that allows me to check if a number is a valid French telephone number.

It must be like this:

```
0X XX XX XX XX
```

or:

```
+33 X XX XX XX XX
```

Here is what I implemented but it's wrong ...

```
/^(\+33\s[1-9]{8})|(0[1-9]\s{8})$/
```

Comment: What about home phone numbers and cellphones beginning with `07`?

Comment: `^(((\+33\s)|0)[1-9]\s([0-9][0-9]\s){4})$` may do the trick but it's quite complex and is just and modification from yours (obligation to put space between two digits), but `0033` isn't allowed?

Comment: @Larme it is, indeed

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use:

```
^
    (?:(?:\+|00)33|0)     # Dialing code
    \s*[1-9]              # First number (from 1 to 9)
    (?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){4}   # End of the phone number
$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dsi0Pw/2)

---

It allows whitespaces or `.` or `-` as a separator, or no separator at all

Comment: JavaScript example : `'+33678787878'.match(/^(?:(?:\+|00)33|0)\s*[1-9](?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){4}$/gmi)`

Comment: Compatible with JSON schema: `^((\\+|00)33|0) *[1-9]([ .-]*[0-9]{2}){4}$`

Answer (score 23):

A complex example (the one I'm using):

```
^(?:(?:\+|00)33[\s.-]{0,3}(?:\(0\)[\s.-]{0,3})?|0)[1-9](?:(?:[\s.-]?\d{2}){4}|\d{2}(?:[\s.-]?\d{3}){2})$
```

For example it matches each of these lines:

```
0123456789
01 23 45 67 89
01.23.45.67.89
0123 45.67.89
0033 123-456-789
+33-1.23.45.67.89
+33 - 123 456 789
+33(0) 123 456 789
+33 (0)123 45 67 89
+33 (0)1 2345-6789
+33(0) - 123456789
```

More:

- [**Test it**](https://regex101.com/library/GmDIbg)
- [**Visualize it**](https://regexper.com/#%5E(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5C%2B%7C00)33%5B%5Cs.-%5D%7B0%2C3%7D(%3F%3A%5C(0%5C)%5B%5Cs.-%5D%7B0%2C3%7D)%3F%7C0)%5B1-9%5D(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5B%5Cs.-%5D%3F%5Cd%7B2%7D)%7B4%7D%7C%5Cd%7B2%7D(%3F%3A%5B%5Cs.-%5D%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D)%7B2%7D)%24)

Answer (score 6):

```
var phoneExp = /^((\+)33|0|0033)[1-9](\d{2}){4}$/g;
```

It also takes into account the 0033 scenario.

Comment: why not `^(\+33|0|0033)[1-9]\d{8}$` controlling for 8 numbers instead of 4 times 2 numbers `(\d{2}){4}`? Also if there is no reason to capture, you can dump all but the first group of parens.

Comment: In addition, in JavaScript, if using `new RegExp`, to avoid `SyntaxError: nothing to repeat`, you'll have to double escape the "+" at the beginning. So the final regex would be `^(\\+33|0|0033)[1-9][0-9]{8}$`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
/^(\+33 |0)[1-9]( \d\d){4}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the regex into two separate parts:

- the prefix that can either be `+33 X` or `0X`
- the rest of the number (`XX XX XX XX`)

Regex would be:

```
^((?:\+33\s|0)[1-9](?:\s\d{2}){4})$
   ^ non-capturing group for prefix
                      ^ non-capturing group for number
 (                                 )
 ^ actual capture group from your original regex
```

This only allows whitespace as a separator; if you want something more open, [Thomas Ayoub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38484020/5323213) is more verbose.

[tested on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rD8iF6/2)

NOTE:
As per Thomas's comment, since the regex is a full match using the start and end tokens (`^$`), the capture group is rather unnecessary. You can then take it out to look like this:

```
    ^(?:\+33\s|0)[1-9](?:\s\d{2}){4}$
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the credits. As the string is a full match (`^$`) I'm not sure that the capturing group is necessary. Also, `+33 0 12 34 56 78` is not a valid number...

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Ah, my lack of knowledge of how phone numbers works is to blame for that. Will edit. And very true about the capture group, I just wanted to reflect OP's original intent. Will make a note of it.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx for format: **0X XX XX XX XX** **+33 X XX XX XX XX**

```
^(0|\+33 )[1-9]([-. ]?[0-9]{2} ){3}([-. ]?[0-9]{2})$
```

Answer (score 1):

In a java based application, you can use this dependency to validate phone numbers:

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
         <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Example of use:

```
  public static boolean isValidFrenchPhone(String portalPhone) {
    try {
        PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
        Phonenumber.PhoneNumber number = phoneUtil.parse(portalPhone, "FR");
        return phoneUtil.isValidNumberForRegion(number, "FR");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a long time since the question was asked but I tried couple of solutions in that post. None of them satisfied my requirements so I came up with this custom/heavy one that does the job for France number (in any format, I think) and also Belgium phone numbers.

```
    def phone_pattern():
        """
                \+\d{2}[-.\s]?(?:\(0\)|0)*?[-.\s]?          # Dialing code +CC00(0) or +CC00 or +CC00 0
                00[-.\s]?\d{2}[-.\s]?(?:\(0\)|0)*?[-.\s]?   # Dialing code 0033 \(0)|0
                (?:\(0\)|0|)\d?[-.\s]?                      # First number (from 1 to 9) preceeded by a non mandatory 0 or (0)
                (?:\d{2}[-.\s]?){3,4})                      # End of the phone number (3 or 4 times 2 following digits separated or not by .- )
                (?:$|\D)                                    # Anything but a number or the end of string    
        :return:
        """
        # To be improved to make the 0 mandatory when +33 or 00 is missing. Ex it will match 234558899
        # return re.compile('((?:\+\d{2}|00[-.\s]?\d{2})?[-.\s]?(?:\(0\)|0|)\d?[-.\s]?(?:\d{2}[-.\s]?){3,4})')
        # This version should tka
        return re.compile('((?:\+\d{2}[-.\s]?(?:\(0\)|0)*?[-.\s]?|00[-.\s]?\d{2}[-.\s]?(?:\(0\)|0)*?[-.\s]?|0)\d?[-.\s]?(?:\d{2}[-.\s]?){3,4})(?:$|\D)')
```

Answer (score 0):

+33 only is for metropolitan France.
I think you can also add overseas France with

```
/^(?:(?:\+|00|0)((262|692)|(263|693)|508|(5|6)90|(5|6)94|(5|6|7)96|681|687|689))(?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){3,4}$/
```

If you consider digits length difference between overseas territories as well as some specific area codes for mobile, the regex becomes really messy...

The function I'm currently using in JS :

```
export const isValidFrenchPhoneNumber = (phonenumber) => {
    const metropolitanFranceReg = new RegExp(/^(?:(?:\+|00)33|0)\s*[1-9](?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){4}$/)
    const overseasFranceReg = new RegExp(/^(?:(?:\+|00|0)((262|692)|(263|693)|508|(5|6)90|(5|6)94|(5|6|7)96|681|687|689))(?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){3,4}$/)
    // src: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_France
    // 262, 263 = La Réunion, Mayotte and IO territories ; 508 = Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon
    // 590 = Guadeloupe, Saint-Martin et Saint-Barthélemy ; 594 = French Guiana (Guyane) ; 596 = Martinique
    // 681 = Wallis-et-Futuna ; 687 = Nouvelle-Calédonie
    // 689 = French Polynesia
    return !(phonenumber.match(metropolitanFranceReg) === null) || !(phonenumber.match(overseasFranceReg) === null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version compatible with a lot of OCR imperfections (for example for scanned restaurant receipts):

```
"(\s*0\s*[1-9]\s*\.?\s*([\s.-]*\d\s*){8})"gmix
```

or Python flavor version with a group:

```
(?P<french_number>\s*0\s*[1-9]\s*\.?\s*([\s.-]*\d\s*){8})
```

working examples:

```
06 01 02 03 04
0 6 01 02 0 3 04
 0 7 01 02 03 04
 0 7 .0   1. 02 .03. 04
0 7.01.02.0 3.04
0 7-01 - 02-0 3    - 04
```

The international prefix has been omitted.

Make sure you remove spaces with a string replace call for each group.

[Regex sandbox here](https://regex101.com/r/VBiGuW/1)