# how to validate password's length using mongoose scheme?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In my mongoose Schema i used below code for the password field..but  it doesn't check for the minimum length for the password..what is wrong here??

```
 password:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    match:/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/,
    minlength:5


  },
```

Answer (score 3):

It is actually working correctly. You probably harshed your password in the controller and when you do this the harsh will most likely always will be greater than 8 characters in length. This is harsh is what you are checking for in the schema in the schema and since it is will always be greater than 8 then it would work fine but this is what you want. The best way is to check and enforce this is in your controller. I actually ran into this same issue today and this was how I solved it.
Code example:

```
const registerUser = (req, res) => {
    const { email, password] = req.body;
    // check if password length is greater than 8.
    if(password.length < 8) {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error('Password must be at least 8 characters long');
        }
    //.... the rest of your code.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hop hop hop! wait a minute. You do not store the password directly in database ; because of security concerns.

---

**How to store passwords :**

- Get the password from the user
- Hash it using an algorithm, like sha512 (long time ago md5 ...)
- Store the hashed passowrd

---

**How to check password match :**

- Get the password from the user
- Hash it using an algorithm
- Compare the stored password with the calculated hash

---

[Here](https://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-sha512/) is a blog explaining about how to hash a password in node.js.

---

**As example :**

```
const crypto = require('crypto'),
    text = 'hello bob',
    key = 'mysecret key'

// create hahs
const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', key);

hash.update(text);

const value = hash.digest('hex');

// print result
console.log(value);
```

---

About the check of the password, you can make it inside of the function handling the hash, like :

```
function checkPassword(pass) {
  if (!/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/.test(pass)) {
     throw new Error('E0001');
  }

  // Password is acceptable
}
```

Comment: I hashed the password..That code is  in my api.js file... does the password length mention above belong to the hashed password? or to original one??

Comment: If you hashed the password before you stored it, then your regex and minlength apply to the hash string. Which is not what you want to do. You cannot perform the password check at mongoose validate like you are trying to. Look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588032/mongoose-password-hashing).

Comment: but i used this to check mobile number..here also mobil no's length is not validated  ..what is the problem??

Comment: mobile:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        minlength:10,
        maxlength:10
        
    },

Comment: @Sandz `minlength` and `maxlength` are available only for `String` type. You can see it [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html). You shouldn't store the number as a `Number` but as a `String` type.

Comment: but I want to check whether the mobile number should includes only numbers..what to do then ??

Comment: Use a regex [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483885/regex-for-french-telephone-numbers)