# minLength property in User model not working

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, backend

Everything is working perfectly fine except for the minLength property of password.

If I send { "email" : "harshit@example.com", "password": "abc" } from Postman,
it still works even though I've set minLength to 6.

minLength property of email is working perfectly good but not of password.

> server.js

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
    var user = new User(body);

    user.save().then((doc) => {
        res.send(doc)
    }).catch( (err) => {
        res.send(err)
    })
});
```

> user.js // using mongoose here.

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', {
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minLength: 5,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            validator: validator.isEmail ,
            message: `{VALUE} is not a valid E-Mail`
        }
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: 6, // This line isn't working
        trim: true
    },

    tokens: [{
        access: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: did you add this options after compiling your first model?
if so you need to delete it and recompile

Comment: I think your question is answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255854/12194198

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) you're supposed to use `minlength`, notice the lowercase `l`.